# How to use network scanner (Samsung Clx 2160n)

Tags: networking, scanning

I have a Samsung Clx2120N multi-functional (scanner, printer and copier) and this is connected to router (home office), I have two computers and one notebook in the network, but no has a server printer, all equipment send jobs for print direct, they have a network printer configured. I tried several times to install the scanner and I don't have success. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you edit you answer to clarify whether you are talking about 2120N or 2160N please?

Answer (score 2):

System -> Administration -> User and Groups and add 'cupsys' user to the 'shadow' group.

Get the [driver from Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportDownloadCenter.do?prd_ia_cd=N0000189&prd_mdl_cd=CLX-2160N&prd_mdl_name=CLX-2160N). Go to cups admin localhost:631 with your browser then click on the Administration tab

- Is printer detected?

  - Yes! click on the button to Add your detected printer
  - No! Click on Add Printer

    - Select 'Internet Printing Protocol (ipp) enter the IP Address of your printer
    - Use provide a PPD File (because I don't think printer is in the list?)
    - Click on Browse to find were to find driver stuff you downloaded, PPD file here
    - Click on Modify Printer, Authentication -> enter username and password here
- Printer is installed

  - Click on the Printers tab
  - Any Warning Message

    - If `rastertosamsungsplc` is not found or something like that then

      - Copy raster* files to `/usr/lib/cups/filter/`
    - Reboot

Comment: Sorry did not read the answer before, but installing the printer on the network ok, I had no problems using it normally, including the upgrade to version 4.11, ubuntu it automatically search the network and install, and my scanner probelema the network does not work, I can not access it on any machine, is it possible for windows with the correct drivers, the solution I currently use is to scan to a thumb drive. I wonder if I can even use the scanner to make the network available on Linux.
Thank you.